# Ninject with EF multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, ninject

Good morning everyone!

I just started working in the project where I see there is an memory leak.
The situtation is as below. There is a console application which basically runs all the time in the `while(true)` loop.

There are bunch on classes which does some logic in the loop.
Each class has Execute() method where inside create uses Task.Run() method where the call is not awaited by anyone. 
The list of above classes are called Engines. All engines are stateless classes which are stored in in array in main Program.cs class.

The code basically looks like:

```
private static List<BaseEngine> Engines;

public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitializeDI();
        RunProgram();
    }
    private static void RunProgram()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var engine in Engines)
                {
                    engine.Execute();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //handle
            }
            finally
            {
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
            }
        }
    }

    private static void InitializeDI()
    {
        _kernel = new StandardKernel();
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new NinjectServiceLocator(_kernel));
        NinjectConfig.Setup(_kernel);
    }
```

The sample engine looks like:

```
public class SampleEngine : BaseEngine
        {
            public override void Execute(Task task)
            {
                var someService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDbContext>();

                System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    // some action using dbcontext
                });
            }
        }
```

In above example of SampleEngine it uses to get IDbContext from Ninject DI. However other engines could use another services regiestred in DI.

All the dependencies are registered as `InCallScope()`

Basically its like mostly all engine its about fire and forget the given method using Task.Run(). 
What I did is changed Execute method to return the Task and after this task ran to completion I used to `Dispose()` this task. This did not bring any value.

I did some investigations and I saw that the problem is inside `Ninject.Activation.Cache`. I can do the manual cache clean which helps but I know the problem is somewhere in the code but I cannot find it.

Since every dependency is registered as InCallScope() they should be disposed after each task begin to the end. I dont see anything holding reference to these objects because every engine is stateless .

I used ANTS to see the some information and this just keeps growing each minute:
[image]

And this points to the Ninject caching as below:

[image]

Looks like the DbContext is not disposed and still exist in Ninject cache. Is it a problem of alot of tasks in the system or I do anything wrong ?

Thanks in advance
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The most simple approach seems to be embedding the using in your task. But it is a blind shot, as it seems your code is simplified. You don't use the `task` parameter in your method.

```
public class SampleEngine : BaseEngine
{
     public override void Execute(Task task)
     {    
       System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
       {
         using (var someService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDbContext>())
         {
           // some action using dbcontext
         }
       });
     }
}
```

For a more advanced approach, here is [an interesting link](https://github.com/revoframework/Revo/blob/27414af6c7e2098587594ede4e6ab77bb299daa7/Revo.Core/Core/NinjectBindingExtensions.cs#L47). It features a `InTaskScope` binding. It is based on AsyncLocal and custom tasks through extensions of TaskFactory